# Ampersand usage for naming a file in unix

Tags: unix

What does an ampersand before a variable name mean?

I have a file which uses a variable for naming the file.

Eg var1=2015
Then the file is named as
Xyz&var1

Can anyone please help me in understanding what an ampersand here means?

Comment: It means whatever the application creating the file wants it to mean

Comment: More to the point, if you can [edit] your question to state which exact application was used for naming this file, we might be able to answer it. As it stands, any "answers" are going to be guesses, and since we don't do guessing games here on Super User, I have voted to put your question on hold so it can be clarified.

Comment: One guess, it is all about bash and the `&` should be a `$`, which would make sense.